# How to visualization of a Json object using graphs with class diagram in angular

Tags: json, angular

I want to display a class diagram with a graph which connects the classes using JSON object like in the image. And this diagram should be interactive to the user. Is it possible to achieve it using libraries in angular? or any other way to bind the JSON data into an interactive class diagram with graphs?

[image]